# How could this doubly linked list search code be implemented?

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

I got this code which is supposed to provide an algorithm that searches for the item in the middle of a doubly-linked list.
There may be one or more flaws in the code making the code not executable.
How can this code be implemented to make it work using a linked list?
And what are the problems in the code itself?

```
node1 = self.head
node2 = self.tail

while node1 != node2: 
    node1 = node1.next
    node2 = node2.previous
return node1.value
```

Comment: What is this algorithm supposed to search for?

Comment: That's a good one. It is supposed to find the value in the middle of the list.

Comment: How do you define "the middle"? For example, if your list has 4 elements.

Comment: *"There may be one or more flaws"*: you are not sure? What is the problem you encountered?

Comment: This code is given to me to improve, but I must start by first spotting the obvious flaws. In my perspective, it does little to nothing. I guess the answer from @NathanFurnal gets it. Since the code is so brief and there hasn't been any obvious handling of an even-sized list, that may be the thing, to begin with.

Comment: You should test the code with lots of linked lists and see whether it returns the expected result for each. Have you done that?

Comment: A somewhat quick and dirty solution would be to keep track of the length `n` of the list in an attribute and increment/decrement the value on the relevant operations. Then, the middle would be `n//2` in the odd length case and `n//2 - 1` in the even length case. To find the middle, you'd just iterate over the list up until the limit. This would also ensure you don't need to care `next` elements being `None` and you don't need to check for missing the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you 'step' both nodes at the same time inside the loop.
You can thus miss the middle because they can jump over each other without being detected.

You should step one node at a time in each loop iteration.
The solution could be something like this:

```
node1 = self.head
node2 = self.tail

step_node_1 = True
while node1 != node2:
    if step_node_1:
        node1 = node1.next
        step_node_1 = False
    else:
        node2 = node2.previous
        step_node_1 = True

return node1.value
```

Answer (score 1):

> what are the problems in the code itself?

There are these issues:

- It may be obvious, but the code must be placed in a *function*, as otherwise `return` is a syntax error. Moreover, since there is a reference to `self`, this suggests that function is a *method* of the linked list class.
- If the list is empty, then `node1` and `node2` will be `None`. When `node1.value` is executed, there will be an exception. You need to deal with the empty list case properly
- If the list has an even number of nodes (and is not empty), then `node1` and `node2` will walk passed each other, and will continue until they reach the other end of the list and become `None`. Then again the same exception as above will occur. You can solve this by also checking that `node1` and `node2` are (not) neighbors

Here is a correction & completion of the code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, nxt=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = nxt
        self.previous = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = self.tail = None

    def push_front(self, value):
        self.head = Node(value, self.head)
        if self.tail:
            self.head.next.previous = self.head
        else:
            self.tail = self.head

    def get_mid_value(self):
        node1 = self.head
        node2 = self.tail

        while node1 != node2 and node1.next != node2:  # Neighbor check
            node1 = node1.next
            node2 = node2.previous
    
        if node1:  # Guard
            return node1.value

# Demo
lst = LinkedList()
lst.push_front(2)
lst.push_front(1)
print(lst.get_mid_value())
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is empty `self.head` and `self.tail` will be `None`. And in the last line you will `return None.value` which will cause an error.
And look at this example:
list have 4 nodes n1, n2, n3, n4

before loop

`node1 = n1,  node2 = n4`

1. iteration

`node1 = n2,  node2 = n3`

2. iteration

`node1 = n3,  node2 = n2`

node1 and node2 are not same even they points to middle elements.
loop continuous

3. iteration

`node1 = n4,  node2 = n1`

4. iteration

`node1 = None, node2 = None`

and at the end node1 and node2 are same so loop breaks. Then because node1 is equal to `None` `return None.value` will be called which causes an error.
Your code should look like this:

```
node1 = self.head
node2 = self.tail
    
while node1 != node2 and node1.next != node2: 
    node1 = node1.next
    node2 = node2.previous
        
if node1 != None: return node1.value
```